# Why My Conditional Tag Didn't work in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In My Wordpress Blog [BuildinBit](http://www.buildinbit.com). I Try To Assing H1 to post title rather than blog title on single posts and single pages.
And on the Home page, Archive page, Category and Search Page.I  Try To Assing H1 To My Blog Title.
For This I Use Following Code:

```html
<?php
   if(get_header_image()) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img id="logo" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"/></a>
                <p id="tagline"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
    <?php
   } else {
    ?>


<?php if(is_home() || is_category()|| is_tag() ||is_archive() ||is_search() ){
<h1 id="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

}else
{
<span id="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></span>
}
?>

<?php
   }
    
   ?>
```

But This Code Didn't work it show HTTP Error 500 on all pages.

Comment: You are doing wrong. try with this code.

Comment: <?php if(is_home() || is_category()|| is_tag() ||is_archive() ||is_search() ){
echo '<h1 id="title"><a href="'.esc_url(home_url('/')).'" title="'._e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' ).'">'.bloginfo('name').'</a></h1>';

}else
{
echo '<span id="title"><a href="'.esc_url(home_url('/')).'" title="'._e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' ).'">'.bloginfo('name').'</a></span>';
}
?>

Comment: Zaid I Forget To Mention My Complete Code. I Think I am Using A conditional tag inside a Conditional tag. I  Updated my Code please take a look

Comment: @AjayMalik Stop using capitals on every word, it makes your question hard to read.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Don't put code in comments please, it's completely unreadable. If you think you can solve the problem with your code, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Clonkex ok thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Close php tag like this

```
<?php if(get_header_image()) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img id="logo" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"/></a>
    <p id="tagline"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></p>

  <?php } else {  ?>

    <?php if(is_home() || is_category()|| is_tag() ||is_archive() ||is_search() ){  ?>
         <h1 id="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

   <?php  }else { ?>

         <span id="title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'back to home', 'blogkori' );?>"><?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?></a></span>
   <?php 
  } 
    } ?>
```

Comment: Pawan This Code is correct by i update my whole code and I think I am Using a conditional tag inside another conditional tag please take a look at updated code

Comment: Thanks, Pawan Your Code Really Work and I set it as answer